# How to replace exact number of characters in string based on occurrence between delimitors in R

Tags: r, regex, backreference

I have text strings like this:

```
u <- "she goes ~Wha::?~ and he's like ~↑Yeah believe me!~ and she's etc."
```

What I'd like to do is replace all characters occurring between pairs of `~` delimitors (including the delimitors themselves) by, say, `X`.

This `gsub` method replaces the substrings between `~`-delimitor pairs with a single `X`:

```
gsub("~[^~]+~", "X", u)
[1] "she goes X and he's like X and she's etc."
```

However, what I'd really like to do is replace each and every single character between the delimitors (and the delimitors themselves) by `X`. The desired output is this:

```
"she goes XXXXXXXXX and he's like XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX and she's etc."
```

I've been experimenting with `nchar`, backreference, and `paste` as follows but the result is incorrect:

```
gsub("(~[^~]+~)", paste0("X{", nchar("\\1"),"}"), u)
[1] "she goes X{2} and he's like X{2} and she's etc."
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `paste0("X{", nchar("\\1"),"}")` code results in `X{2}` because `"\\1"`  is a string of length 2. `\1` is not interpolated as a backreference if you do not use it in a string pattern.

You can use the following solution based on `stringr`:

```
> u <- "she goes ~Wha::?~ and he's like ~↑Yeah believe me!~ and she's etc."
> str_replace_all(u, '~[^~]+~', function(x) str_dup("X", nchar(x)))
[1] "she goes XXXXXXXX and he's like XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX and she's etc."
```

Upon finding a match with `~[^~]+~`, the value is passed to the anonymous function and `str_dup` creates a string out of `X` that is the same length as the match value.

Comment: Thanks. Works beautifully. Just for curiosity sake: is a solution with backreference possible?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Backreferences like `\1`, `\2` are only supported in *string* replacement patterns. When you use a function and pass a string containing backreference syntax, it is treated like an independent string, not a replacement pattern. After that function processes the string, the result becomes the string replacement pattern. To evaluate the backreference, you need to pass the match object / value to an anonymous function.